# Prove limit exists if and only if left and right limits exist and are equal

Tags: calculus, analysis, limits

Prove $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=L \iff \lim_{x\to a^+}f(x)=L=\lim_{x\to a^-}f(x)$

I have no problem with the $(\Leftarrow)$ direction but I can't do it for the other direction. Proofs for both directions would be nice.

Comment: I think that *precisely* the direction you have no problem with is the hard one, as the existence of limit *means* that it exists no matter how $\;x\;$ approaches $\;a\;$ and thus it is the other one which is almost trivial...

Comment: Is there a typo in $\lim_{x\to a^+}f(x)=L+\lim_{x\to a^-}f(x)$? Maybe the $+$ was meant to be a $=$?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 3):

The definition for the limit of the function says:

> If a limit $$\lim_{x \rightarrow a}f(x)=L$$ exists, then given any real number $\epsilon>0$, there exists another real number $\delta>0$ such that
>   if $0< |x-a| <\delta $, then $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$.

Now let us consider the first case, that is: $$\lim_{x \rightarrow a}f(x)=L \implies\lim_{x \rightarrow a^{+}}f(x)=L$$

For simplicity let us only consider a monotonously non-decreasing, continuous function. The proof will apply similarly to others.

We know that  $\forall$ $\epsilon >0$ $\exists$ $\delta>0$ $:$ $x<a+ \delta$ $\implies$ $f(x)<L+ \epsilon$

Now consider an $0<\epsilon_0<\epsilon$. Then there must exist a $\delta_0$  that satisfies

- $\delta_0<\delta$, because remember that $f(x)$ is monotonously non decreasing and continuous in our interval
- $x<a+\delta_0$ $(=a^+ )$ $\implies f(x) < L+\epsilon_0<L+ \epsilon$

Hence, by the definition of the limit we have: $$\lim_{x \rightarrow a^+}f(x)=L$$
A similar proof can be used for the other side.

Comment: In the definition $L$ is defined to be the result of $f(x)$, so $|f(x) - L|$ is always zero. So, the whole part with $ϵ$ and $L$ could be freely omitted in the definition, isn't it? Similarly, $f(x) < L + ϵ$ is always true. And finally, as someone who came here from google, trying to understand the question in the topic, I struggle to see in which part did you answer, why as $lim_{Δx \to 0}$, $x + Δx ≠ x + (-Δx)$ implies that the limit doesn't exist.

Comment: Okay, I found the answer. Turns out, it's not something that can be proved, rather just a definition, not mentioned for some reason on Wikipedia: there's a left and right limits *(obvious)*, and "the limit", defined to exist in terms of left and right ones. I.e. it's like a factorial of zero, just an agreement.

Answer (score 3):

you can prove it by contradiction. assume that 1) the lim from the right = L and 2) the limit from the left = M, and assume that 3) the Lim = L. by definition 3) implies that the limit from the left is L which contradicts 2).

Repeat and assume that 3) the lim = M. this will contradict 1) this time.

therefore, by elimination the only possible value for the Lim = Lim from left = Lim from right.